# How to explain and visualize a Q Learning Agent?

Tags: data-visualization, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

What are some common visualization approaches used in explaining the behavior of a Q-Learning agent?

Here is an excerpt of some example Q values for 5 actions serialized to json:

```
[
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 9.7180743908492411E-05, 0.0, 6.0134871150517619E-05, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 2.7866205412015394E-05, 0.0, -3.5352503282357707E-05, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.002179680102508753, 0.0, 0.0003821282886147801, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.00044976255425384565, 0.0, 2.6171104054710165E-05, 0.0 ],
  [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
```

Comment: Yes, these QValues are from a working agent. In terms of the visualization, exactly this: just looking for visualization approaches that will assist in understanding the behavior that given state values in a certain range the agent has encountered a particular type of reward.

Answer (score 1):

To visualise your Q values, you can you a heat map. See e.g. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html, if you are using Python.

Comment: Thanks. How do you think I could go about decomposing the states into multi-dimensional features?